# Properties Panel Not Showing in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, line-art

Hoping that someone can help. When working in Illustrator, the Properties panel just stopped working:

[image]

Whether I have a line or text selected, Properties stays 'closed' and does not open. I've also tried going to Window > Properties, but it doesn't have any effect. I thought that maybe this could be caused by not having the most recent version of Illustrator, so I updated to 2021 and also updated my OS to MacOS Big Sur, but the issue still remains.

[image]

Of course, I need the Properties panel to adjust line width and other shape attributes. If I can't get the Properties panel to show, is there any other way to adjust line width in Illustrator?

Thanks

**Edit**: I am at least seeing a way to edit the width of the stroke by going to the Stroke panel. But I'd still need Properties to change the end of a stroke from Cap to Rounded (and other things).

Comment: You can doubleclick on stroke panel for it to open the cap properties. In general you should go trough every panel and expand them as much as possible. Either by dobleclicking or going trough the hamburger menu and expand them. Once you do you realize properties panel is just a stupid substitute and that illustrator defaults actually hinder you from using the software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont actually need properties panel for setting stroke width (or cap or arrowhead or dash). You can use the stroke panel which is superior in every way. There is literally nothing i personally use properties panel for because everything it does is inferior to other methods.

But the reason why you dont see the properties panel is that its collapsed. Try doubleclicking the properties tab on the right. If that fails try dragging it out of your dock this should expand it. And finaly if all else fails try to reset workspace to defaults.